# How to create a file in informatica with header and footer when there is no data coming from source?

Tags: informatica

I have the following scenario.

In informatica, for a process flow which takes 2 input files, do union#1, derive the header and footer and do another union and load the Union#2 output to the target file.

But, even in case of blank file from source., I need to generate the file with header and footer(footer with the count as 2).

Expected content in target file, if we get blank sources:

HYYYYMMDDCODE1315           (header)
TYYYYMMDDCODE1315 0000002   (trailer with no.of records)

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 3rd input file - a dummy file with 1 column and 1 row. Full outer join this dummy file with the output of first union before deriving header/footer. Use a dummy column with the same value as in the file in the join condition (e.g. 1 = 1)

This way, there will be at least 1 row coming out of the joiner even if the actual input files does not have any data. Later you can filter out the dummy record by checking if the actual source fields are NULL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Samik! But, How to manipulate the data to generate the same file when we get data (with data, header and footer) or the file with only header and footer when we don't get any data?

Comment: You don't need to manipulate any data. If you are getting 10 records from source, the joiner would also produce 10 records, and you header/footer derivation logic should work as it is. When there is no source data, the joiner would still produce 1 row from the dummy file. (It should be a full outer join instead of left outer, corrected the answer)

Comment: That make sense. Thank you! But to derive the footer(as it has count(no.of rows) involved in it) , I still need to get the values from #union1 to trailer transformation. So getting the records, both from joiner and union#1 to the trailer transformation is something challenging I am not able to proceed. Sorry, I have updated my scenario.. Please see if you can help.

Comment: Well, I guess you can drag all ports from union1 to joiner. So, you will get all ports from joiner itself. For the no data scenario you can hardcode the count as 2, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pre-session command that will echo a header line to a file. Then in the session just append the data to an existing file (check the `Append if Exists` box).
Use post-session to append a footer line.

Comment: Can I add a Date to the header while doing this? As my header should be like "HDATECODE"

Comment: Anything you can echo. How to echo date in a given format is a separate question. Give google a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all this complex processes, I was able to get this using the following command in post session command in informatica.

if [ ! -s $PMTargetFileDir/$OutputFile1 ];then echo "H""$(date +"%Y%m%d")""$(date +"%Y%m%d")""XXX"""> $PMTargetFileDir/$OutputFile1;echo "T""$(date +"%Y%m%d")""$(date +"%Y%m%d")""XXX""""00000000002""" >> $PMTargetFileDir/$OutputFile1;fi;

Thank you all for your inputs!